# What Ubuntu versions are affected by CVE-2022-0847

Tags: bug-reporting, vulnerability

I have been informed about [the CVE-2022-0847 vulnerability](https://www.cve.org/CVERecord?id=CVE-2022-0847). I'm wondering what versions of Ubuntu are affected by such a bug.

Comment: Why ask us? Canonical has a website for this https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2022-0847 "needs triage" so it is unclear at this moment

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry! Thanx

Comment: It might be worth commenting on the LTS release of Ubuntu 20.04.  Ubuntu 20,04 shipped with kernel 5.4, which is old enough to not be affected by CVE-2022-0847.  However, if you installed a point release update (an Ubuntu 20.04.x), or if you have installed a newer HWE kernel on Ubuntu 20.04, then your system may well be affected.

Comment: @Rinzwind - 'needs triage' doesn't answer the question. See my answer below.

Comment: The kernel patch released on 9/3/2022 *does not* handle this particular CVE, but it addresses 3 other ones: https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-5318-1

Answer (score 9):

I can confirm that kernel versions `5.13.0-28-generic` and `5.11.0-40-generic` for Ubuntu 20.04 *are* affected.

Answer (score 5):

Given the incredible severity of this CVE, I did a lot of research on this.

Yes, this has been patched and pushed (as of 2022-03-08) for 21.10 (**Impish**).

Update 2022-03-09:

A comment below
(@fuzzydrawings), mentioned the fix was pushed to 20.04 (**focal**) as of 2022-03-08.
I believe various versions of 18.04 (**bionic**) have been released as well. I have linked the commits for impish and bionic below.

Also:

https://ubuntu.com/security/notices can be helpful, and
https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-5317-1 is the notice for this CVE. **However** it only mentions 21.10 and 20.04 LTS. I linked below to the commits for bionic that contain the fix.

**21.10 (impish)**

After I did a `sudo apt update`, I did a
`sudo apt list --upgradable` to see if the kernel was updated.
It was.

The important line is here:
`linux-generic/impish-updates 5.13.0.35.44 amd64`

Googling for the answer didn't come up with any clear answers. So I went to the ubuntu git repository at:

[https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/impish](https://git.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/impish)

(this URL is specific to impish)

You can then see that this version contains the patch from Max Kellerman:
[https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/impish/commit/?id=181cbcef9f8c158189a3b1094c532b6686f14acf](https://git.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/impish/commit/?id=181cbcef9f8c158189a3b1094c532b6686f14acf)

The following commit tags it:
[https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/impish/commit/?id=b07bbb7a296b9be80e48973bba8b03fb1101547f](https://git.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/impish/commit/?id=b07bbb7a296b9be80e48973bba8b03fb1101547f)

`linux (5.13.0-35.40) impish; urgency=medium`

**20.04 (focal)**

the two kernel versions have received the update (5.4 and 5.13 HWE).
Here are the commits:

[https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/focal/commit/?id=114ece9d1f915886450030af5333287437bbf74b](https://git.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/focal/commit/?id=114ece9d1f915886450030af5333287437bbf74b)

[https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/focal/commit/?id=438da6e5c849ffe553fc15379471bf331346c3d2](https://git.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/focal/commit/?id=438da6e5c849ffe553fc15379471bf331346c3d2)

**18.04 (bionic)**

the two kernel versions have received the update (4.15 and 5.4 HWE).
Here are the commits:

[https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/bionic/commit/?id=aeae4fd15ccbf0012f84d792ea7aef08e299da30](https://git.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/bionic/commit/?id=aeae4fd15ccbf0012f84d792ea7aef08e299da30)

[https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/bionic/commit/?id=10de766b07707fc67eb3e0a7ffcbaa27603d7c64](https://git.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/bionic/commit/?id=10de766b07707fc67eb3e0a7ffcbaa27603d7c64)

Comment: @user535733 - good idea. I didn't check those. I will edit now.

Comment: I just received a patched kernel through Ubuntu focal 20.04 repository, so can confirm the update has been pushed for 20.04.

Comment: Your links are invalid - I dont' see anything except this error: `Repository '%7Eubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/impish/commit' not found.`

Comment: @ArturMeinild - I just checked. The links work.

Comment: @fuzzydrawings - thanks, I will update the post.

Comment: According to the promoted comment at the bottom of [this Ars Technica story](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2022/03/linux-has-been-bitten-by-its-most-high-severity-vulnerability-in-years/), the vulnerability requires two separate bugs.  The second bug (and, hence, the vulnerability itself) was introduced in kernel 5.8.  The first bug was introduced sometime prior.  If correct:  This would seem to imply that kernels below 5.8 are not vulnerable.  Updates to kernels below 5.8 are likely therefore fixing the first bug.  But those kernels were not vulnerable.

Answer (score 2):

It's very likely that all Ubuntu releases with 5.8 kernels or later are currently affected as no patches for this have been released at this moment.

Comment: @marcelm - I believe you misread Bill Lipa's answer.  Specifically, Lipa did not say what you quoted him as saying.  I believe Lipa's answer is accurate as written.

Comment: @mpb You are right; It seems I misread the answer as _"currently unaffected"_. My apologies! Bill, I downvoted your answer based on my misinterpretation, and now I [can't undo that vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80762/why-do-votes-get-locked). If you edit your post (perhaps add some references or pointers to further information?) that restriction is lifted. Sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

**All ubuntu versions without patch** `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` **from version** `5.13.0.35.40~20.04.20` **are affected by CVE-2022-0847**

**How to check it:**

1. run terminal
2. run command: `apt list --installed | grep linux-generic`

If you see message (command run on ubuntu 20.04) `linux-generic-hwe-20.04/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.13.0.35.40~20.04.20 amd64 [installed]` it means, that patch is applied and is't affect on your ubuntu.

**How to install it:**

1. run terminal
2. run command: `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-hwe-20.04`
3. confirm it by pressing <kbd>Y</kbd> key.