# How to install patch CVE-2022-0847?

Tags: updates, security, patch

I see a new security patch update: `CVE-2022-0847` for my Ubuntu 20.04. I need to install it or check it for updates. Due to the article I see keyword - Linux and I tried to install patch using the command `sudo apt-get install linux` due to the original name is `linux_5.4.0-104.118` so, but unfortunately I get error `Unable to locate package linux`.

I tried to check updates: `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. No updates. So, maybe this patch is already installed.
How to check it?

Comment: Please clarify and link to your sources of information. Which article and keyword? Also see [this question about CVE-2022-0847](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1396518/what-ubuntu-versions-are-affected-by-cve-2022-0847). AFAIK it isn't patched yet.

Comment: [link](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&searchon=sourcenames&keywords=linux&_ga=2.65831533.2126810672.1646813277-508026709.1643269256) there are text: _You have searched for source packages that names contain linux in all suites, all sections, and all architectures. Found 100 matching packages._ and in the bottom of page is packages: _Download linux_ section...

Comment: Please read the other question I linked to.

Comment: the topic can be closed due to the link, provided by Artur Meinild

Comment: I think yes. I run command `apt list --installed | grep linux-generic` and saw version `5.13.0.35.40~20.04.20` it contain CVE patch, so my ubuntu is up to date with this new patch/